# Register Value 8086

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, x86-16

```
If AL contains the value 10 and AH contains the value 10 what does AX contain?
```

I Know AH and AL are two 8 bit registers and AX is AH and AL joined together to be a 16 bit register.

The way I worked this out is that AL contains the value 10 which is the value 0001010             in the register and the same for AH. Then AX is those two registers together. So The end value I have for AX is 2570 am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.
You can easily confirm this by bringing up the calculator on Windows, go `View` -> `Programmer`, select the `Bin` radio button, type in the binary digits (don't worry about the leading zeros), then select the `Dec` radio button.

Comment: Thank you it was revision for an exam and I just wanted to make sure i was on the right track!